# Cannot drag and drop to debugged-application run from a privileged-run Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, drag-and-drop, privileges, windows-explorer

I'm debugging my application which has drag-n-drop features in Visual Studio 2010. I have to run the IDE in privileged mode since some of my project required so.

*My problem:*

I can drag-drop when run the .exe file normally (run from Windows Explorer (WE)) but when debugging in VS2010 I cannot do drag-dropping between my app and WE.

I tried to open WE in privileged mode but still cannot debug either.

Do you have the same problem? If you do, do you have any work-around for it? Please share.

Answer (score 6):

Another workaround is to run the debug binary from Windows Explorer and attach to the process from within Visual Studio via the "Tools" or "Debug" menu. I have verified that drag events are received in the debugger when using this approach.

Answer (score 5):

This is by design, an aspect of UAC called UIPI (User Interface Privilege Isolation).  It prevents a non-elevated process from hijacking an elevated one through Windows messages or drag and drop.  It protects against shatter attacks.  There is a way for the elevated process to explicitly allow messages with ChangeWindowMessageFilter.  But not for drag and drop, it isn't message based.

There is no decent api-level workaround for this, it has to be done declaratively.  The manifest for the program needs to use `uiaccess = true`, be code-signed with a certificate from an approved authority and be installed in c:\windows or c:\program files.

Comment: @Passant So sad to hear that :( Disabling UAC is a fine workaround for me. If you know how to toggling UAC on/off quickly, eg. using command line, I'd love to use it.

Comment: @Passant One more thing about turning off UAC is that we need to reboot the OS :(

Comment: @Passant I've posted question about this here http://superuser.com/questions/227860/how-to-toggling-uac-on-off-quickly-eg-using-command-line-in-windows-7. Please join with us if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks @Hans, It worked. I have been struggling with it for so long. Crazy UIPI. Have a great day my friend.